# MySQL return count of each element AND return all occurrences of that element

Tags: mysql, sql

I can get a count of the number of times each element occurs using the following MySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM example
GROUP BY example.value
```

The problem is, because of the GROUP BY statement, duplicate records will not be returned with their COUNT value.

IE I need this:

1. apples - 2
2. apples - 2
3. oranges - 1
4. bananas - 3
5. bananas - 3
6. bananas - 3

But I get this:

1. apples - 2
2. oranges - 1
3. bananas - 3

Any ideas how this could be done? I am thinking some kind of a join, but I can't figure out the proper way to compare the table to itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
select a.*, b.cnt
from example a
join (
    select value, count(*) cnt
    from example
    group by value
    ) b on a.value = b.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.value, t.count 
FROM example e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM example
  GROUP BY example.value) t
ON e.value = t.value;
```